# Understanding how the distribution of a python script is achieved with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm looking to distribute a few python scripts. The scripts use a few separate packages such as docopt and of course utilise various libraries. Id like to be able to package my script up along with everything it needs to function correctly.

From what I have read the best way to do this is to use setuptools and the use of a setup.py script. What Id like to know is, is setuptools able to identify what packages and libraries are being used in my script and automatically copy all the relevant packages from their current location into another directory to be used for the 'New Package' creation. Or do I have to manually find the package installations on my system and copy them to the relevant folder for the 'New Package' creation?

Ive read the setuptool docs but from what I have read it seems as though I need to do it all manually? If so how do I know exactly where all the relevant packages and libraries are on my system?

Could someone let me know if Im understanding this correctly?

Comment: Try it without doing it manually and see.

Comment: I have taken a look thats why Im asking if my understanding is correct. It just seems strange that would be as manually as I think it is. Surely it must be able to do it automatically.

Comment: @martineau Ive read the setuptools docs and distutil docs. I have just attempted creating a setup.py with the basic metadata, then used setup.py dist to create a package. As expected it didnt do anything buy create a dist dir with my script file and a setup.py file. None of the modules,libraries used in my script are copied into the dist director. So safe to assume your meant to collect all packages manually place them in the same directory?

Comment: Try `setup.py build`. You may also find [Getting Started With `setuptools` and `setup.py`](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) useful.

Comment: I have read them and attempted both sdist and build. After the package is created I tested installing from the setup.py via `python setup.py install` but the required packages do not install. I get the following error `python setup.py install
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got it working.

Just in case anyone else comes across this post and wants to know what to do simply.

The idea is that you have a script you would like to share, but this script uses various other modules, packages etc. The last thing someone wants to do is start scrapping them all together to create a nonworking manual package.

By creating a setup.py file and specifying what packages you want included with your script this can all be automated. The automated includtion of the all the "required packages" is done during the install process (so someone has your newly shared script and is installing it using easy_install).

To generate a distribution package for your script you need to do the following.

- Identify which packages you will need to include (check out your code).
- Move your script to a new folder (this will be the package container).
- Follow the instructions in this [post](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) to create the relevant files youd like in your distribution. (Note the "install_requires" field)
- Execute `python setup.py sdist` from the commandline making sure your current working directory is that of your new package.
- Your distribution package is now in the dist dir.
- Pass this your friends. They will need to install setuptools/easy_install from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).
- Once installed they can install your package by executing `easy_install packagename-0.1.0.tar.gz`. This will now install all required packages and of course your script.